# Возможна ли сборка проекта для продакшина в конечные файлы без Node и Webpack?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

Добрый день.
Я новичок в технологиях связанных с `NodeJs`, `Vue.js` и `webpack` - но меня интересует следующий момент.

Если во время разработки проекта я использую все эти технологии.
В том числе запускаю весь проект с помощью `NodeJs` и сервера с ним связанного + `webpack` - могу ли я каким то образом для продакшина трансформировать свой проект в обычные `HTML + CSS + Js` файлы без вышеупомянутых технологий ?

Если да - то стоит ли так вообще делать, если например стороне сервера планируется на `django` или на других технологиях не связанных с `Js`?

Если перефразировать вопрос и зайти с другого угла - то например при запуске проекта с `NodeJs` и `webpack` используется сервер.
При запуске страниц на `django` используется свой сервер.
Каким образом сделать так что бы один проект мог использовать на фронте Вью а на стороне сервера к примеру `Python django`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что формирует связка для фронтэнда, может быть прикручено во `view` для любого движка.
А любой бэкэнд перенести уже не выйдет, разные языки.

Comment: Мне вот что не понятно:
Как я понимаю в вашем варианте проект будет запускатся с помощью сервера работающего в паре с джангой.
Но как в этом случае будут работать шаблоны Вью например?
Должны ли оставатся при этом в проекте файлы вебпака, вью лоадера и пр. примочки вью + самое главное должна ли присутствовать Нода при этом?

Comment: Если да - то как все это будет работать(на Django) без запуска Нодовского сервера?

Comment: Нет, связка билдит фронтэнд в обычный HTML + CSS + JS, который можно перенести в шаблоны любого движка и, отдавая их браузеру, последний их корректно поймёт, то же происходит и при сервере на ноде.

Comment: Тогда остается один вопрос:
Каким образом все эти технологии смежные с Vue билдят все файлы проекта в обычный HTML + CSS + JS.
Что за технология компилирует одно в другое?

Comment: Ууу, куча программистов тратила сотни человекочастов, клепая скрипты, которые передавая друг другу эстафету работы и делали по кусочку работы, создали такой шедевр. Если кратко: нода запускает вебпак, тот смотрит модули, в поочерёдно их запускает, каждый из них как-то модифицирует исходный код (например, Babel строит AST, обходит его своими плагинами из пресетов, собирает обратно в текст и отдаёт; минификатор тоже строит дерево, по внутренним правилам вырезает лишнее, собирает и отдаёт и т. д. и т. п), трансформированный код сохраняется в указанное место.

Comment: А какая команда запускает процесс подобной компиляции?
(в общем что бы я погуглить мог и почитать подробней об этом)

Comment: Зависит от настроек. Если идёт через ноду, то в `package.json` настраиваешь команды типа `"dev": "webpack-dev-server args..." и запускаешь `npm run dev`. Если вручную - пишешь саму команду в консоли: `webpack-dev-server args...`.